# Fibonacci numbers with initial two values as parameters

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci

I have been trying to make a infinite fibonacci list producing function that can take first 2 values as parameters.

Without specifying the first two values it is possible like this

```
fib = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

Suppose I wanted to start the fibonacci sequence with 5 and 6 instead of 1,1 or 0,1 then I will have to change the above code. But when trying to make a lazy list generator in which I can specify the first 2 values of fibonacci sequence I am stumped. I came up with this but that didn't work.

```
fib a b = a : b : zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

The problem is obvious. I am trying to convert the use of list in the hard-coded one. How can I solve that?

Comment: well... you still could `zipWith (+) (fib a b) (tail $ fib a b)`, even though that's of course is inefficient

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about

```
fib a b = fibs where fibs = a : b : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

? Use the same method, but with your parameters in scope.

I should add that, in case you are tempted by

```
fib a b = a : b : zipWith (+) (fib a b) (tail (fib a b))  -- worth trying?
```

the `where fibs` version ensures that only one infinite stream is generated. The latter risks generating a fresh stream for each recursive invocation of `fib`. The compiler might be clever enough to spot the common subexpression, but it is not wise to rely on such luck. Try both versions in `ghci` and see how long it takes to compute the 1000th element.

Comment: I used `takeWhile (< 1000000) $ (fib 1 2)` for both the versions. Didn't time it. The difference was apparent without any timing necessary. First one was much faster compared to the second one.

Comment: note that "the" Fibonacci numbers should always be `[0,1,1,2,...]` because this gives nice properties like `gcd (fib !! x)(fib !! y) = fib !! gcd x y`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do that is:

```
fib a b = a: fib b (a+b)
```

This stems from the inductive definition of the Fibonacci series: suppose we have a function that can produce a stream of Fibonacci numbers from F<sub>i</sub> onwards, given F<sub>i</sub> and F<sub>i+1</sub>. What could that function look like? Well, F<sub>i</sub> is given, and the rest of the stream can be computed using this function to produce a stream of Fibonacci numbers from F<sub>i+1</sub> onwards, if we can provide F<sub>i+1</sub> and F<sub>i+2</sub>. F<sub>i+1</sub> is given, so we only need to work out F<sub>i+2</sub>. The definition of series gives us F<sub>i+2</sub>=F<sub>i</sub>+F<sub>i+1</sub>, so, there.

Comment: This is much clearer than @pigworker 's answer. It might be more efficient.